# how to write an UserException which throws multiple checked exception

Tags: java, exception

how can i write an UserException class which can throw multiple checked java exception?
should i extend Throwable class?
it would be better if u can give me a simple demo of this throwing two exceptions.
the main aim of this question is that i want to reduce no. of try and catch block statement in my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Every thread can have at most *one* exception that is *currently being thrown and not yet caught*. Tell us the complete story of what you want to do, otherwise we have to guess too much.

Answer (score 0):

Roland is right, a method can throw only one exception.

Maybe an exception hierarchy is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way throw "multiple exceptions", sort of. You could throw one Exception wrapped in another, like this:

```
throw new UserException(new SomeException());
```

When this is caught, the catcher can find out the cause like this:

```
catch (UserException e) {
    Exception cause = e.getCause(); // cause is an instance of SomeException
}
```

This way the catcher has access to both exceptions.

Define `UserException` as extending Exception:

```
public class UserException extends Exception {

    private UserException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    private UserException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```